# Best practice way to read input in Java 5

Tags: java, unix, command-line, exception, console

I'm writing a tutorial for kids, to learn programming on the Java 5 platform.

What's the best way to read in text data from a console program?

By "best" I mean the most common way this would be done at the Java 5 level. I realize reading text input from the command line is fraught with challenges and that a well guarded method would have to incorporate several levels of exceptions, that's fine. At this point in the tutorial, I've covered basic output, basic program structure in Java, exception handling. If you think additional things need to be covered before user input, I'd welcome suggestions.

It's interesting that doing a web search on this question doesn't give an immediate answer, there's a lot to weed through and there's no sense of a best practice. I guess it's because there are so many hidden caveats, it's not as simple as it first seems.

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

class Example {

    private BufferedReader br;
    private String inputString;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String inputString = null;

        BufferedReader br =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.print("\n > ");

        try {

            inputString = br.readLine();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            System.out.println("\n IOException called.");
        }

        System.out.println("\n Input was: " + inputString);
    }
}
```

You would compile this using: javac Example.java

Run it using: java Example

Is there a better way you can think of that might be more instructive for children? Funny how basic these things seem to be, but when you really look at it, that's a lot of code for gathering one line of text with a minimal amount of error checking.

If you want to add an optional comment about how you first got interested in programming, I'd be hugely grateful. For me, it was chance (my father had to bring home a dumb terminal to do work from home, connecting to his work's mainframe over a dial-up connection to a unix system, and when he showed me how to list 'games' I was hooked).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If your target are kids without any preexisting knowledge, maybe go with one of the languages that avoid all the boilerplate code? In python you could replace all this with a three liner without having to worry about classes, exceptions and whatnot (well for production code you obviously DO have to worry about the stuff, but for children "It runs" is probably enough)

Comment: I would say its best practice to use a supported version of Java, either Java 6 update 26 or Java 7.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Scanner is pretty basic and less code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
         Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
         String inputString = s.nextLine();
         //Output stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok that's really helpful. Do you think it's better to stay away from the details of user entry at this point? That was where I was heading, and if Scanner allows this, it might be best. I'm just not sure how instructive it would be to use. When you use BufferedReader, you have to enclose reads in a try/catch block, which at least will give a student a hint about the complexities involved with parsing textual user input.

Comment: I don't know if I'd necessarily teach beginners about try-catch blocks.  They're going to have enough problems understanding control flow as is.  Scanner is what I was taught as a beginner, and we didn't cover try-catch until using Scanners on files, much later in the course.  If you really want, you can use Scanner to read an int using `nextInt()` and place that inside a try-catch, as an InputMismatchException can occur if they enter non-ints.

Answer (score 2):

I think a `Scanner` is a bit easier than a `BufferedReader`, personally. That's how I learned user input initially.

You have to do some of the same things but you can leave off the exception handling and try/catch for a later day.

Comment: Thanks - how do you handle exceptions with Scanner then? What if the user enters something the read method can't handle? Actually, more to the point, what kinds of input might the user enter that could potentially throw an exception with Scanner? Great entry, thanks, I put a lot of weight on people's personal experience with the answers they give.

Comment: @dvanaria You can check with hasNextXXX before using nextXXX, or you can just catch the according exceptions (as the jdoc states this would be `InputMismatchException` or `NoSuchElementException`) - personally I prefer the latter when reading protocols or something since it's imho clearer and has one singular error case.

Answer (score 1):

Some rhetorical questions:

- What age are the kids?
- What are you aiming to achieve in terms of educational outcomes?  Or is this mainly about giving them something fun to do.
- What is **your** level of experience with Java?

My gut feeling is that you should not be going overboard with the "best practice" stuff.  Assuming that these are school age kids, they don't need it, they probably don't have the outlook to understand it.  So for most of them it is going to be boring blah blah, and a good way to turn them off IT.

Besides, it is difficult to teach "best practice" if you don't fully understand it yourself.  The way I see it, "best practice" is about techniques that are best most of the time.  To teach them properly you need to understand (and be able to explain) why they work, and when they don't work.  It also helps if you understand a bit about the "not best practice" ways of doing things too ... so that you can explain the difference.

(I'd also question why you are restricting yourself to Java 5 ... but that's not particularly relevant.)

---

When I asked about "educational outcomes" I was mean things like:

- student gets/stays enthusiastic about programming, or
- student achieves such and such a level of proficiency, or
- ...

It is one of the first questions that someone in the business of teaching should be asking themselves.

Having said that, I think I'll stick with my advice above.  If you want to beat the drum about "best practice", try to structure your material so that it is easy for the average kid to skip over the "boring" bits.

Comment: Hey, great questions. I'm aiming for kids around 9 to 13 years of age, that's about when I got interested in programming. For educational outcomes, that's actually the whole point of my tutorial. I'm hoping to draw interest from kids who wouldn't normally be labeled as geeks or computer nerds (not that there's anything wrong with that, ha). My own experience with Java is about 5 years of programming at a hobby level. My bachelor's degree was mainly based on Java but that is only a year's worth of experience at best. Thanks for the questions.

Comment: Also will add: there's no reason for the Java 5 restriction, that's just the platform I'm building my tutorial on. I'm trying to stay away from the details of various releases. In a production environment, I find that Java 5 is still most widely used these days. I like a lot of the features of Java 6, it's was just a decision I had to make at the time I started.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is that , kids are going to be more exited when they see their result with a new screen using JOptionPane.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class test{
public static void main(String[] args){
String name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter your name");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Name: " + name);
}
}
```